# Django: detect admin login in view or template

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I detect, from views or template file, if my admin user is logged in or not? For example, use case for my site:

1. User opens `/admin/`, enter correct credentials
2. Then user open some page, for example `/page/` and there are "Add" and "Delete" buttons
3. User opens `/admin/` and click "Log out"
4. `/page/` -> there are no "Add" and "Delete" buttons

Django version 1.4

Comment: Please set the right comment as solution!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Joseph's answer is fine for your simple case, but in reality neither `is_staff` nor `is_superuser` is a perfect fit. Assuming your page is, say, `/polls/` (a list of `Poll` objects, in an app called `poll`), you should test the specific `poll.change_poll` and `poll.delete_poll` [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/#default-permissions).

In a template:

```
{% for poll in polls %}
    {% if perms.poll.change_poll %}<a href='/polls/edit/{{ poll.id }}'>Edit</a>{% endif %}
    {% if perms.poll.delete_poll %}<a href='/polls/delete/{{ poll.id }}'>Delete</a>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or in a view [using `has_perm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm):

```
if not request.user.has_perm('poll.change_poll'):
    return HttpResponseForbidden('Nope!')
```

Or in a view [using a decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator):

```
@permission_required('poll.change_poll')
def edit_poll(request, poll_id):
    # ....
```

You can assign these permissions directly to a user, to a group (and then put a user in that group) or by setting `is_superuser`.

Comment: The page of "permissions" is not working, please update it;

Answer (score 137):

In templates:

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <p>Hello, admin.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Hello, ordinary visitor.</p>
{% endif %}
```

In views:

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
    # Hello, admin.
else:
    # Hello, ordinary visitor.
```

Depending on your needs, `is_staff` might be a better fit than `is_superuser`. You can read about the difference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the privileges a user has and just want to make sure they are logged in, you can use `user.is_anonymous`, which will be true if the user is logged out and false if they are logged in.

By default, `user.is_staff` is required for the user to have access to the Django Admin.